# Help to make this type of design

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would love to know what technique I can use in illustrator to create this type of logos using lines. As much as I have tried, I do not achieve these effects.

I leave you some samples to see if you can help me.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? I can appreciate the desire to learn, but you really should show your attempts and where you are struggling. This isn't a "tutorial on demand" website.

Comment: Hi Sorry, I am new user, sorry, I will try not to do it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The designs you show don't really rely on any special "technique" and can't be said to use an "effect". They are simply geometrical shapes.

I won't give you a step by step tutorial, but try to point you in the right direction. I'll ignore the third example which stands a bit out and is harder to make than the others.

---

First of all you need to learn the basic tools of Illustrator. You have to be able to:

- [Draw shapes](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/shapes-basics.html)
- [Move, align and distribute objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/moving-aligning-distributing-objects.html)
- [Use the Shape Builder Tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creating-shapes-shape-builder-tool.html)

---

Then you need to train yourself to look at a design and break it down into the shapes it's made of.

Let's focus on your second example:

[image]

See how it can be divided into a circle and 12 rectangles:

[image]

The circle is drawn with the *Ellipse Tool* and the rectangles are drawn with the *Rectangle Tool*, grouped in pairs and equally spread out using the *Align Panel*.

---

Once you have drawn these shapes, it's easy to use the *Shape Builder Tool* to build the shapes you need:

[image]

Comment: Woow, thanks so much.

Thanks for your attention and comment, I think this will help me a lot. Sorry if I have not used this community very well.

Only one question, for example 1, it could be used with the same technique or other things would have to be discussed. How to adapt some lines to a shape like a number or letter?

Comment: Don't be sorry, but yeah this question is too broad. You should check out the links I posted and tutorials. It will make it easier to figure out how to make these things yourself. To make example 1, you could do something very similar to what I showed with the Shape Builder Tool. Like [this](https://i.imgur.com/CrtGY6X.gif). It would also be common to instead use the [Pathfinder](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/combining-objects.html) panel or use a [Clipping mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html).

Comment: This question might be closed with the "Needs more focus" reason, but just in case it doesn't, please *accept* the answer if it was helpful. That is what makes users able to see which answer the questioner preferred.